# UIImageView* XXX = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:XXX]

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, animation, random, uiimageview

WHat does this line of code :

```
UIImageView* flakeView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:flakeImage];
```

if it help Then I have this :

```
int startX2 = round(random() % 480);
// set the flake start position
flakeView.frame = CGRectMake(startX2, 330.0, 30,  20);
flakeView.alpha = 1;

// put the flake in our main view
[self.view addSubview:flakeView];
```

Answer (score 1):

The line:

`UIImageView* flakeView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:flakeImage];`

creates a container `"UIImageView"` object that contains an image `"UIImage"` stored in an ivar `flakeImage`

The rest of the code positions `flakeView` on the main view with assigned x,y,width and hight properties.

Comment: yes but when I want that flakeImage collide with another I don't know what happen but without touching the other it collide I think it's due to the container . HOw can I solve this ?

Comment: You wanted to know what this line of code did and I told you I don't know what are you talking abut collisions? Your code here is just initialization of one view!